# Predicting a ratio, max values known. Should they be inputs?

Tags: regression, correlation

I am trying to predict the ratio between variables $a$ and $b$. I know the max values $a$ and $b$ can take and qualitatively the ratio "should" either be close to $\frac{\max(a)}{\max(b)}$ or to $1$ (and it drops to $1$ as total load $a+b$ decreases).

I do not know the value for either $a$ or $b$, those are outputs of the calculation. I do know $a+b$. In total I have nine input variables and about 200 data points. I want to avoid overfitting as much as possible, but I have to hit the target to less than 1% or the model will be scrapped.

I am considering using a neural net, or possibly (simpler) a linear regression with higher order terms of the inputs. My question is, is there any way to get more information out of the max values then simply using them for inputs? Any suggestions as to a model that leverages those knowns is also appreciated.

The problem comes from engineering, basically we are doing load balancing between two machines. Both machines will run near their maximum capacity until the load drops and they should share more equally.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, and your goals here? What are these variables? What is the other variable? Is max(a)/max(b) >1 or <1? Would you use a or b (hopefully not both) as predictors?

Comment: We have a prediction model where each component of a system is modeled using principles from physics, but we do not have a good model for the entire integrated system. The ratio between these variables is important to understand load balancing, but the load balancing is done in the control system, and it uses maximum values for the hardware. So we are left with a chicken and the egg situation.

Comment: There are a little less than 200 data points. We do not know $a$ or $b$, only their maximum values, which correspond to hardware sets. There are two other variables which are categorical (hardware and control schemes), and four other inputs. We can generate more data but it is expensive. We need a very close fit, not only to the data, but for any validation point in the area.

Comment: I know it is neigh impossible without overfitting, but I must match the data to less than 1%.